# What is a regular expression for inserting a string into a Find and Replace match?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I need a regular expression to replace all instances of:

```
Session["ANYWORD"] ==
```

with

```
Session["ANYWORD"].ToString() ==
```

I have `Session\["\w+"]\s==`, which correctly *finds* the right matches, but I don't know how to insert `.ToString()` into the match.

What, or perhaps more appropriately, *is* there a regular expression to do what I need to do?

Comment: You'll want `Regex.Replace` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In particular the `Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)` overload I think since the MatchEvaluator will let your replacement be dependent on what you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put the value that is between the square brackets into a **capture group**, and substitute that in your replacement.

In short, this will do it:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"Session\[(""\w+"")]\s==", @"Session[$1].ToString() ==");
```

where `$1` will insert the contents of your first capture group (determined by parenthesis in the pattern -> `()`).

You can also use named groups if you like, then it becomes:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"Session\[(?<anyword>""\w+"")]\s==", @"Session[${anyword}].ToString() ==");
```

[Here is the MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that particular overload of `Regex.Replace`.

For more information about capture group substitution in .NET, [look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).